# How to return multiple sliver widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am building a Flutter app using Slivers and Provider.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(),
      Consumer<CustomerController>(
        builder: (context, model, child) {
          if (model.loading) {
            return Loading();
          }
          else {
            return Header();
            return Saved();
            return Recommendations();
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

- **Loading** returns a SliverFillRemaining
- **Header** returns a SliverToBoxAdapter
- **Saved** returns a SliverList
- **Recommendations** return SliverList

Basically in my app, SliverAppBar is always displayed.

Now depending upon the model's loading state, the rest of the sliver widgets needs to be rendered. But I can only use return once which doesn't render Saved and Recommendation widgets.

How do I solve this problem? How do I return all the sliver widgets specified in the `else` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this handy package - [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools).

And used it like this

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(),
      Consumer<CustomerController>(
        builder: (context, model, child) {
          if (model.loading) {
            return Loading();
          }
          else {
            return MultiSliver(
              children: [
                Header(),
                Saved(),
                Recommendations(),
              ],
            };
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to display all three slivers you have to make `Consumer` widget as parent widget. Have a look in below code.

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CustomerController>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        if (model.loading) {
          return Loading();
        } else {
          return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(),
            Header(),
            Saved(),
            Recommendations(),
          ]);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: In this case, Sliver App Bar will not be shown when loading is occuring.

Comment: Yeah, In order to display appbar you  need to wrap the `Loading` widget inside `Column` widget and add custom appbar (Not SliverAppbar) above `Loading` widget.